# Find value which is nearest minimum of the key

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();

        map.put(30, "");
        map.put(20, "");
        map.put(50, "");
        map.put(60, "");
        map.put(70, "");

        System.out.println(map.containsKey(20));

    }

}
```

What I am trying to do from above above code

1. Trying to search a number is in map or not
2. We can easily check if a key is available or not using containsKey

If key is not available then I need fetch nearest minimum key from the
map.

For example if trying to fetch 40 which is not available in map then
contains key throws false then it will return 30 because its the
nearest minimum number of 40.

How to get that?

Comment: From your example 30 and 50 are both 10 away from 40. How do you decide that its 30? Only numerical keys?

Comment: I need nearest minimum value not maximum. so 30 is less then 40

Comment: A HashMap is not a good data structure for this kind of requirement. Try with a tree.

Comment: Try this `map.keySet()
                .stream()
                .filter(key -> key < YOUR_VALUE)
                .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
                .findFirst().orElse(null);`

Comment: I don't java have something like this built in, do you want function?

Comment: [NavigableMap.floorKey](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NavigableMap.html#floorKey%28K%29) is designed to do exactly this.

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this:

```
map.keySet().stream()
            .filter(key -> key < YOUR_VALUE)
            .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder()) 
            .findFirst().orElse(null);
```

Or

```
map.keySet().stream()
                .filter(key -> key < YOUR_VALUE)
                .min(Comparator.reverseOrder())
                .orElse(null)
```

Comment: what if your keys are made up of higher values only?

Comment: @Slkrasnodar will return null. `orElse(null)`

Comment: @Slkrasnodar , in that case the result will be null.

Answer (score 0):

This will work. But need a bit modification if your input is the minimum number

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();

    map.put(30, "");
    map.put(20, "");
    map.put(50, "");
    map.put(60, "");
    map.put(70, "");

    System.out.println(getNearestMinimum(map,31));

}

private static int getNearestMinimum(Map<Integer, String> map, int key){
    int minimum = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int minDif = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for (Integer integer : map.keySet()) {
        int dif = key - integer;
        if(dif >= 0 && dif< minDif){
            minimum = integer;
            minDif = dif;
        }
    }
    return minimum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For your case HashMap isn't the rigth data structure better Use NavigableMap to use  floorKey and ceilingKey will get the nearest or current key for you. 
Other way better do a sort Algoritm on  HashMap keyset and  fetch the nearest

```
int key = 20;
NavigableMap<Integer, Object> map = new TreeMap<Integer , Object>();

Integer before = map.floorKey(key);
Integer after = map.ceilingKey(key);
if (before == null)  System.out.println(after);
if (after == null)  System.out.println(before);

System.out.println((key - before < after - key 
        || after - key < 0) 
        && key - before > 0 ? before : after);
```